# CSS add pseudo element on focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I want to display the close icon, on focus. It already shows on hover with React Bootstrap, but I want it to display on focus as well and it is not showing the circle. When I hover on `li tag` it shows the close icon (this is using react bootstrap). Now I want the same icon to display on focus on `a tag`.  [Here's the working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/9bo81jyy/)

My HTML:

```
<div class="test">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="navtabs">
      <li>
        <a href="showMe/1">
          <div class= "inside">
            <div class="delete">
              <i class="fa-times-circle"> </i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.nav > ul.navtabs > li > a:focus > .fa-times-circle::before {
  content: "\F057";
}
```

Comment: Maybe just copy/paste problems but you are missing two right carets in this code. One on your `a` tag and one on your `i` tag.

Comment: You seem to have misspelled the icon class name in your markup. Everything should work if you change `<i class="fa-time-circle">` to `<i class="fa-times-circle">` (note the missing **s**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`>` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp) you are using means that `.fa-times-circle::before` will only be selected if it is the immediate child of `a:focus`. But it's not – you have two divs between them in your HTML.

Remove the `>` selector so that your overall selector looks like `.nav > ul.navtabs > li > a:focus .fa-times-circle::before`, and it should work.

Also be sure to close up your `<a>` tag. You're missing the `>` bracket after the `href`.

Comment: removed > but it still does not show the the pseudo element

Comment: @ksernow make sure to close your `<a>` tag, and if it still doesn't work, you'll need to reproduce the issue in a Stack Snippet so we can see the problem in action. From the info you provided, it should work.